# Class With Data Structure Paramater Class C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Could someone checking for my code class if it possible to do like this, I got null inside class value. for detail check below :

**classLogBarter.cs** // Make a class

```
[System.Serializable]
public class classLogBarter {
    public string DisplayName;
    public string PlayerID;
    public int CommentID;
    public string Time;
    public List<item> ItemBarter = new List<item>(); // Here is that possible ?

    public classLogBarter (string playerid, string displayname, int commentid, string time, List<item> itembarter // Here how about this ?) {
        PlayerID = playerid;
        DisplayName = displayname;
        CommentID = commentid;
        Time = time;
        itembarter = new List<item> (); // Is this correct ?
        ItemBarter = itembarter; // Is this correct ?
    }

    public classLogBarter Clone() {
        return new classLogBarter (PlayerID, DisplayName, CommentID, Time, ItemBarter);

    }

    public classLogBarter() {

    }
}
```

**LogBarter.cs** // Add Value to the class // Asumption that BarterItem Variable Have 1 or 2 Value.

```
public List<classLogBarter> LogBarter = new List<classLogBarter> ();
public List<item> BarterItem = new List<item>(); // Asumption that BarterItem Have 1 or 2 Value. Here now have BarterItem[0] and BarterItem[1]

LogBarter.Add(new classLogBarter(playerID,displayNames,1,times,BarterItem));
```

**// Debug.Log to show the LogBarter value**

```
for (int i = 0; i < LogBarter.Count; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < LogBarter[i].ItemBarter.Count; j++) {
                    Debug.Log ("Player LogBarter : " + LogBarter [i].ItemBarter [j].itemName); // Here there is no value in here.

                }
}
```

What i want to ask is why when Debug.Log LogBarter[i].ItemBarter[j].itemName there is no item ?

Is there anything that i have miss ? or i am just do a mistake in how creating the class with paramater class ?

Comment: What is meant by "Assumption have 1 or 2 values"? Why do you assume it has values? Are you adding them somewhere? If that is all your code, what you have is a list ready to add items, but no items in there.

Comment: Yes I have adding them before LogBarter.Add. So i have assumption that BarterItem Have already have 2 values inside the class. Do you get it now ?

Comment: Could you check the class how i put the class item inside class. Is that right or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `classLogBarter`, on constructor.

You are overwriting the value that has those 2 values you are not getting:

```
itembarter = new List<item> (); // Is this correct ?
```

Remove that line and you should get the items and not null now.

You are creating a new empty `List<item>` but you already done that and filled it with (you said) 2 values, but when entering constructor, you are assigning a new empty one to the same variable that was holding the already filled one.